# Monoprice Select IIIP Plus - Best speed settings and speeding up prints

Tags: ultimaker-cura, speed

How do I speed up prints for the Monoprice Select IIIP Plus printer?

The manual shows [Cura] examples of:

- Print speed: 50mm/s
- Travel Speed: 80mm/s
- Bottom Layer Speed: 20mm/s
- Infill Speed: 50mm/s
- Outer shell speed: 15mm/s
- Inner shell speed: 30mm/s

However, this doesn’t line up with their advertisements online of a 150mm/s printing speed.

Are there better settings to use, especially ones which can speed up printing time? Or are there any other measures which I can take in order to reduce printing time in general?

Comment: What do you mean by "best"? Best for *what*? Print speed, or print quality? Or somewhere in the middle?

Comment: Somewhere in the middle?

Comment: @iAdjunct, your original question was very close to what would normally closed as "too opinionated". Therefore I made some slight changes to your question so that it has a more general application and is more objective. Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my experience a print speed of 50-70mm/s is ideal. Even if you set the speed to 150mm/s the print head still changes directions often and rarely will have enough time to accelerate from 0->150 before changing direction again.

Some more effective ways of speeding up prints is to adjust

- Layer height
- Infill percentage (15-25% for regular prints, more if they need to be more sound)
- Supports
- Number of shells, etc

Comment: Thanks for your reply. (1) what speed is that? There are six different speeds... (2) how do I pick a good/better layer height?

Comment: I’ve found that 20% fill and 2 shells (or whatever the default is) to be what I need for most things. Supports I decide on a case-by-case basis. The problem is that even relatively simple prints become 36-hour monstrosities (24 as estimated by Cura, which is *always* an under-estimate by a good margin)

Comment: @iAdjunct, could you send an example to a 'simple' print that's taking longer than you expected? 36 hours is a very long print unless you're printing something huge.

Comment: For the plus the layer height should be multiples of 0.04. How low you go depends on you preferences and the model. 0.12mm will give you fine detail but will be mind-numbingly slow. [This article might be helpful](http://my3dmatter.com/influence-infill-layer-height-pattern/).

Comment: @iAdjunct there are 6 different speeds which are all for different processes.  If you really want to go faster then you can change the speeds and see how it prints.  Quality usually drops as the speed is increased.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Cura's default settings for a Prusa I3 on my MonoPrice Select V2 (model #13860), and got horrible results frequently. Then I used the settings you list, and got very nice results. Compare the below images for the bottom layer of 4 benchys, with adhesion brim.

I'm using PLA, 0.4mm nozzle, 60C for bed, 200C for extruder, 1.75mm filament from Hatchbox.

**Default Cura Settings**
[image: Using default Cura settings]

**Listed Settings**
[image: Using recommended settings]

**Settings breakdown**

```
Setting            Cura default    Recommended
Print Speed        60              50
Outer Wall Speed   30              15
Inner Wall Speed   60              30
Top/Bottom Speed   30              20
Travel Speed       120             80
```

**Symptoms of my printer being told to print too fast:**

Material would not adhere properly to the print bed, and would start making clumps. These would rest either on the bed, or on the nozzle itself. The ones on the bed would grow taller than layer height, making the next pass of the nozzle bump against it, further depositing material on it. The clumps on the nozzle would drop at other points, leaving stringing filament all over, and further compromising the next pass of the head.

This might seem like a bed adhesion problem, but the prints were *very* well attached to the bed; I had to apply a lot of force to remove a 15*15cm square from the bed.

Increasing the hot-end temperature seemed to help; at some point we were printing at 230C, well beyond Hatchbox' extrusion temperature range (range is listed as 180C-210C for this PLA batch).

Ultimately, reducing print speed to the settings listed helped us increase print quality back to acceptable levels.

Comment: Please note that answers to questions should answer the question.  You appear to have taken the original post as them giving settings for you to use when they are actually asking how they can increase the speed at which they print.  Stack Exchange sites are not discussion boards so I have flagged this as "not an answer".

Comment: Is this a related question, or an answer?